# SD Library function doesnt work while using second SPI port with ESP32

Tags: spi, esp32, sd

i work on a group project with an ESP32. We have a lcd display and a sd card connected via the two SPI ports of the ESP32.

The card gets initialized with no problem using this code:

```
 bool EKG_recording::initialisation_sd() {

  SPIClass * hspi = new SPIClass(HSPI);

  if (!SD.begin(CS_Pin, *hspi))
  {
    Serial.println("No valid SD card!");
    return 0;
  }

  else if (SD.begin(CS_Pin, *hspi))
  {
    Serial.println("SD card initialized!");
    return 1;
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

One function i have a problem with is used to count every file on the SD card, simple enough right?

```
unsigned short EKG_recording::count_files_from_SD(File dir) {
  while (true)
  {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry)
    {
      // Serial.println("Anzahl der Daten");
      return counter;
    }
    counter++;
    entry.close();
  }
}
```

It once worked without a problem, then we integrated the two SPI ports and now i cant figure out why its not working. 
This part:
`File entry = dir.openNextFile();`
returns false on the first call even though i am 100% sure there are 3 files on the SD card.

I call the function like this :

`File root = SD.open("/");
EKG_recording_1.count_files_from_SD(root);`

But why? Any help is very appreciated.

This is the begin function of the display. Since i didnt write it, i know next to nothing about it.

```
    void EKG_display_control::begin()
{
  // Backgroundlight off
  pinMode(TFT_LED, OUTPUT);
  disable_display_backlight();

  // Initialise Display
  tft.begin(40000000);
  touch.begin();
  tft.setRotation(ROTATION);

  layout_start_screen();
}
```

[image: THE PINOUT:]

[image: The MC+SD Adapter]

Comment: i use a sd adapter, connected via wires to the pins of the ESP32, also added the pinout

Comment: Its just a SD adapter you can also plug into a PC or Laptop. I soldered some pins to it and connected those with the pins of the ESP32

Comment: I also edited the begin function of the display into the main post

Comment: ok. how is SPI for the display initialized? I guess it uses the default SPI object. so everything looks ok.

Comment: I asked my team member and she said the display uses the default SPI

Comment: @Juraj i added a picture to show how the sd adapter is connected. Your help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. It was not too complicated. I just assumed the problem was in the code. This works well enough (dont ask me about the counter--)

```
  unsigned short EKG_recording::count_files_from_SD() {

  root = SD.open("/");
  root.rewindDirectory(); //Sets to beginning of directory


  while (true)
  {
    File entry = root.openNextFile();

    if(!entry){
      Serial.println("Anzahl der Daten");
      counter--;
      return counter;
    }
    counter++;
    entry.close();
  }
}
```

It was just because i used SD.open() always inside the class-functions, so every file root was bound to the class.